# Condense a Pydantic model dict with custom encoder

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, python-3.11

I have two `pydantic` models:

```py
import pydantic


class RoleBaseClass(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str = pydantic.Field(regex=r"^\w+$")


class SubRole(RoleBaseClass):
    ...

class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    subroles: list[SubRole] = pydantic.Field(default=[])
```

If I create an instance of `Role` model like

`role1 = Role(name="role1", subroles=[SubRole(name="sub1")])`

and run `role1.dict()` the result would be

`{ "name": "role1": "subroles": [{"name": "sub1"}]}`.

However, I would like to get rid of the `name` field and when `role1.dict()` is called, would like to condense the result to `{"role1": ["sub1"]}`. Is there a way to achieve this? I did not find any `encoder` for `dict` as we have for the `json` method (`json_encoders`).

Could someone let me know the changes I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a separate model for this because you are describing a totally different schema.

Overriding the `dict` method or abusing the JSON encoder mechanisms to modify the schema that much seems like a bad idea. It makes the model's behavior confusing. The definition of the `Role` schema can be understood by looking at the class and its attributes/fields. But your dumped representation would look completely different.

Conversely, a separate model conveys very clearly that you will be dealing with a different schema. You can define its [custom root type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#custom-root-types) to be `dict[str, list[str]` and set up a [`pre=True` validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) that will allow you to parse regular `Role` objects (dictionaries thereof). If you want, you can additionally enhance that model's interface with things like `__iter__` and `__getitem__` to make it behave more like a dictionary itself.

Here is an example:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator


...  # RoleBaseClass and SubRole

class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    subroles: list[SubRole] = Field(default_factory=list)


class CondensedRole(BaseModel):
    __root__: dict[str, list[str]]

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[tuple[str, list[str]]]:  # type: ignore[override]
        return iter(self.__root__.items())

    def __getitem__(self, item: str) -> list[str]:
        return self.__root__[item]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.__root__)

    @validator("__root__", pre=True)
    def parse_regular_role(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Role):
            return {v.name: [s.name for s in v.subroles]}
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            return v  # invalid
        name, subroles = v.get("name"), v.get("subroles", [])
        if name is None:
            return v  # invalid
        return {name: [s["name"] for s in subroles if "name" in s]}
```

Usage demo:

```py
role = Role(
    name="role",
    subroles=[SubRole(name="sub1"), SubRole(name="sub2")]
)
condensed1 = CondensedRole.parse_obj(role)
condensed2 = CondensedRole.parse_obj(role.dict())
assert condensed1 == condensed2
print(condensed1)          # {'role': ['sub1', 'sub2']}
print(condensed1["role"])  # ['sub1', 'sub2']
print(dict(condensed1))    # {'role': ['sub1', 'sub2']}
```

Notice that by defining `CondensedRole.__iter__` the way we did here, allows us to simply pass a `CondensedRole` instance to the regular `dict` constructor and receive exactly the dictionary you want.

If you want, you can even add a convenience method to `Role` so that you can simply call that to receive a `CondensedRole` object from it. Something like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

...

class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    subroles: list[SubRole] = Field(default_factory=list)

    def condense(self) -> CondensedRole:
        return CondensedRole.parse_obj(self)
```

Extending the demo from above you could then call `role.condense()` to get the same object as you would from `CondensedRole.parse_obj(role)`.

Answer (score 1):

`pydanitc` supports native `dataclass` attributes in native python

Therefore, you can just declar your own `dict`function to the data models to achieve same result

```
class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    """
    Role model.
    """
    subroles: list[SubRole] = pydantic.Field(default=[])
        
    def dict(self):
        return {self.name:[s.name for s in self.subroles]}
```

With your example

```
# input
role1 = Role(name="role1", subroles=[SubRole(name="sub1")])
role1.dict()

# output
# {'role1': ['sub1']}

# empty subroles
role1 = Role(name="role1")
role1.dict()

# output
# {'role1': []}
```